# Организация контроллеров в codeigniter

Tags: url, php, база-данных, codeigniter, sql

Здравствуйте, гуру.

Есть такая структура:

контролеры

```
controller/admin/
controller/admin/staff
controller/admin/client
```

шаблоны

```
view/admin/staff
view/admin/client
```

При авторизации я вытаскиваю значения из бд и делаю проверку.

```
if ($type == 'staff') {
redirect(base_url() . 'staff', 'refresh');
}

if ($type == 'client') {
redirect(base_url() . 'client', 'refresh');
}
```

Если значение равно `client`, то как сделать, чтобы при заходе на адрес `/admin` выполнялись именно контроллеры `controller/admin/client`, и если `staff`, то - `controller/admin/staff`?
Причем адрес в обоих случаях должен быть `/admin`.

**Обновление**

Получилось через роутер

```
$route['admin/(:any)']  = "admin/client";
```

Но мне нужно чтобы значение "admin/client"; client было как бы динамичное

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
```

не так?

Comment: не, получается теперь что
$route['admin/news']  = "$1/news";
то есть вместо $1 должно быть в зависимости от урла admin,client,staff 
а вот :any во втором параметре не работает((

Comment: что не получилось то
скиньте тогда структуру контроллеров и файл config/routes.php

Answer (score 0):

я в роутах сделал так

```
$routes->group('admin', function ($routes) {
/**
 * @todo News
 */
$routes->add('news', 'App\Controllers\Admin\NewsAdmin::index');
$routes->add('news/add', 'App\Controllers\Admin\NewsAdmin::addNews');
$routes->add('news/edit/(:any)', 'App\Controllers\Admin\NewsAdmin::editNews/$1');
$routes->add('news/save', 'App\Controllers\Admin\NewsAdmin::saveNews');
$routes->add('news/delete/(:any)', 'App\Controllers\Admin\NewsAdmin::deleteNews/$1');});
```

в контроллерах

```
protected function views(string $page = 'index', $id = null)
{
    echo view($this->tpl . '/admin/header', $this->rows($id));
    echo view($this->tpl . '/admin/navbar', $this->rows($id));
    echo view($this->tpl . '/admin/' . $page, $this->rows($id));
    echo view($this->tpl . '/admin/footer', $this->rows($id));
}

public function addNews()
{
    $this->views('news/add');
}
```